# Ubuntu installed on Vmware but cannot get access to internet

Tags: networking, vmware, network-bridge, fedora, nat

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on Vmware, the host machine is Fedora 30. However, I cannot get access to internet from Ubuntu. I am not clear how to identify the cause and fix it? Thank you for the help.

Comment: The cause is VMWare's network settings.

Comment: I changed VMWare's network settings from NAT to bridged, because NAT doesn't work, but now Bridged doesn't work too.

Comment: Are you trying to update ubuntu 14.04 ? this Version is EOL.